# Python: How to vstack all the arrays of a column in a dataframe quickly?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, series

How Can I vstack all the arrays of a column into a big array quickly?

For example:

`Dataframe['Binary_feature'][0] = array([[1,0,0,0,1]])
 Dataframe['Binary_feature'][1] = array([[0,1,0,1,0]])
......
 Dataframe['Binary_feature'][i] = array([[0,1,0,1,0]])`

How can I stack all the arrays in column "Binary_feature" into one array like:

```
array([[1,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1,0], ... [0,1,0,1,0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) an array to remove dimensions of size 1:

```
s = pd.Series([np.array([[1,0,0,0,1]]),
               np.array([[0,1,0,1,0]]),
               np.array([[0,1,0,1,0]])])

res = np.array(s.values.tolist()).squeeze()

array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

You will find this more efficient than using `np.vstack` on your series:

```
s = pd.concat([s]*10000)

assert (np.array(s.values.tolist()).squeeze() == np.vstack(s)).all()

%timeit np.array(s.values.tolist()).squeeze()  # 25.2 ms per loop
%timeit np.vstack(s)                           # 71.9 ms per loop
%timeit np.vstack(s.values)                    # 66.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Never use squeeze before :-) nice one

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I will try them all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Data from jpp, `vstack`

```
np.vstack(s.values)
Out[216]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Perfect! This works and very quickly. I just thought to use for loop to solve this, but that causes too much costs I think. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Yvonne.Tian yw:-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

See the [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html) function. For example, if your data is scattered over multiple Excel sheets:

```py
excel = pd.ExcelFile(filename_xlsb)
dfs = [
    pd.read_excel(
        filename_xlsb,
        engine="pyxlsb",
        sheet_name=sheet_name
    )
    for sheet_name in excel.sheet_names
]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `np.concatenate`

```
np.concatenate([df['Binary_feature']])
```

**UPD:** 
In this case it should be `np.concatenate(df['Binary_feature'])`

Comment: @jpp, doesn't he want this? In his example: array([[1,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1,0], ... [0,1,0,1,0]]) is array of arrays.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a *single array* of shape `(n, 5)` where `n` is number of rows.